# iOS - iPhoneX show launch image when change app through home indicator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, launch

I found the app show launch image in iPhone X. When change the app through home indicator, even I didn't write any code for it but still happened.

I have this issues on my project, and saw the same problem in many apps.
I want to keep the launch Image, and not show it while change app.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Video example : https://www.dropbox.com/s/czmpo22fjl6wb0q/531891249.959579.mp4?dl=0

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: Post an image of problem please.

Comment: sorry , put the record video file on dropbox,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/czmpo22fjl6wb0q/531891249.959579.mp4?dl=0

Comment: 1. Are you using launch screen/storyboard? 2. Does it do this on device? maybe its just a simulator issue

Comment: 1. I am using launchImage from storyboard,  2. device and simulator both have this kind of issue

Comment: it's weird. seems like its almost relaunching. If you navigate around does the state get preserved?

Comment: app stata had preserved, thats why I want to remove launch image when the app show

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything... I think it must be a bug.

Comment: I will be try error and wait the solution out ..